# How to replace a multiline string with sed in xml

Tags: xml, sed, titanium

I have the following xml node

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>2.2.1</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>2.2.1</string>
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$buildno</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$buildno</string>
```

The following command only works when the newlines are removed:

```
eval "sed -i.bak  's/<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key<string>2.2.*<\/string><key>CFBundleVersion<\/key><string>2.2.*<\/string>/<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key<string>$NUM<\/string><key>CFBundleVersion<\/key><string>$NUM<\/string>/' tiapp.xml"
```

I have tried using the character N within curly braces but without any luck.

Comment: Do not used text processing tools for `XML` parsing, use a proper `XML` aware tool like `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way:

```
sed -i "" "/<key>CFBundleShortVersionString<\/key>/{n;s/<string>.*<\/string>/<string>2.2.$USER<\/string>/;}" tiapp.xml
sed -i "" "/<key>CFBundleVersion<\/key>/{n;s/<string>.*<\/string>/<string>2.2.$USER<\/string>/;}" tiapp.xml
```